# document.getElements and ejs files

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I noticed the document.getElements is not working for ejs files.
as in below code, I need to **display: none** the div class="delegate".

**myscripts.js**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("delegate").style.display="none";
```

**index.ejs**

```
<div class="delegate"> 

<p>helooo</p>
</div>
```

the error message shows in browser: **Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display')**

can you please help me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting a collection of nodes (actually an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)) but trying to treat them as a single item. The collection doesn't have a `display` property, hence the error message.

You'll need to loop through them all and set the style individually. One way to do this is to convert the array-like `HTMLCollection` to an array first (using `Array.from`, or the spread opertor [...]) and then use `Array.forEach` to update each item:

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName("delegate")].forEach(el => el.style.display='none')
```